# Rounding decimal in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to round downward with SQL server 2008?
E.g. `.96855` is rounded to `.968`.

I.e. up to .96899 I want to round .96899 by avoiding rest.

Comment: You can try `CAST (number AS DECIMAL(10,5))`

Comment: Do you want ".968" or ".96800" output: these are different datatypes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT round(0.96855, 3, 1)
```

-> 0.96800

For 0.968 : `cast(round(0.96855, 3, 1) as decimal(10,3))` works fine.

Ref: [Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) (if last param to Round is anything other than zero, it truncates)

Answer (score 2):

Could this help?

```
SELECT ROUND(123.9994, 3)    
Results: 123.9990  


SELECT ROUND(123.9995, 3)    
Results: 124.0000
```

Comment: @OD: No.. i want  round that value to 123.99 exclude that 90 without rounding...is that possible

Answer (score 2):

`cast(round(0.96855, 3, 1) as decimal(10,3))`