# Microsoft SQL rounding off to whole number, need to 1 decimal place

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate (not round) decimal places in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046/truncate-not-round-decimal-places-in-sql-server)

Can't figure this out. I need 1 decimal place returned while SQL is rounding to whole numbers.

I read that integers divided by integers give integers in SQL, but I need the one truncated decimal place for value of output in the temp table.

I don't mind if 35.0 comes back as 35 but 35.17 should come back as 35.1. Sorry just edited. Need to truncate the last number, not round up.

```
create table #blah(output decimal(9,1))

DECLARE @a money
DECLARE @b money
DECLARE @intinterval decimal(9,1) 

SET @a = 5
SET @b = 2
SET @intinterval = (@b / 1000.0) * (86400.0 / @a)

INSERT INTO #blah (output) VALUES (@intinterval)

SELECT * from #blah

drop table #blah
```

The above equation should give (2 / 1000) * (86400 / 5) = (0.002 * 17280) = 34.56

The 34.56 should truncate to 34.5

Comment: what is the type of your @intinterval variable ? please edit your post. thanks

Comment: What is the declaration for @intinterval?  That is probably where your issue lies.  If I substitute `(@b / 1000.0) * (86400.0 / @a)` for @intinterval in `VALUES (@intinterval)` I get two decimal places in the select statement results.

Comment: Refer this [link][1].You need to cast and use round function


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167299/rounding-decimal-in-sql-server

Comment: Added @intinterval decimal(9,1)

Comment: I tried the link and cast(round((@mnyminbid / 1000.00) * (86400.00 / @mnybudget),3,1) as decimal(10,3)) is still rounding up to 34.6

Comment: Patriotec: You need to round to 1 decimal place, not 3. Try round(round((@mnyminbid / 1000.00) * (86400.00 / @mnybudget),*1*,1). Here's a SQL Fiddle with the calculation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c368d/5. Note that ROUND has three arguments. The second 1 is the number of decimal places. The final 1 in the ROUND is the indication to truncate instead of round up or down, whichever is closer.

Comment: Steve Kass post your answer to my question so I can give you credit. Your solution works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @intinterval = cast(10 * (@b / 1000.0) * (86400.0 / @a) as int) / 10.0
```

or

```
SET @intinterval = cast(@b * 864.0 / @a as int) / 10.0
```

Comment: You answer works, but Steve Kass had the better solution. He answered in a comment, not in an answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What about `Round((@b / 1000.0) * (86400.0 / @a), 1, 1)`, where last 1 saying to truncate instead of round.

Answer (score 0):

try this with no special functions...

if 
a = 5 then output = 34.5 (34.56) 
a = 7 output = 24.6 (24.69)
a = 11 output = 15.7 (15.71)

```
create table #blah(output decimal(9,1))
DECLARE @a money
DECLARE @b money
DECLARE @intinterval decimal(9,2) 
declare @rounded decimal(9,1)    
declare @diff decimal(9,2)
declare @finalvalue decimal(9,1)
SET @a = 5
SET @b = 2
SET @intinterval = (@b / 1000.0) * (86400.0 / @a) 
set @rounded  = @intinterval    -- gets the rounded value
set @diff = @intinterval - @rounded  -- gets the difference whether to round off or not
if @diff >= 0           -- if differnce is >= 0 then get the rounded value  .. eg.   34.31 = 34.3
   set @finalvalue = @rounded 
else                     -- else  subtract 0.1 and get the rounded value  e.g.  34.56 - 0.1 = 34.46 -> rounded value of 34.5
   set @finalvalue = @intinterval - 0.1   
INSERT INTO #blah (output) VALUES (@finalvalue )
SELECT * from #blah
drop table #blah
```

Comment: That is so much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: is not complex mate... just pure mathematics. the thing is he doesnt want it to be rounded off and functions are too expensive.

Comment: It's more complex than it needs to be, as shown by the other answers here before yours.  They give the same behaviour with less code, less cpu time, and can be embeded into a sql query much more directly.  *[I'm not sure what you mean when you assert that functions are too expensive?  `ROUND(x, 1, 1)`, for example, is both a function and less expensive in terms of CPU than this code...]*