# Trouble with SQL decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have run a SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and when my results come through my `Total_Cost` column is not formatted as I want.

I have tried adding in a `Declare @TOTAL_COST decimal(12,2)` clause but cannot seem to get this to work so have taken it out again.

My query is:-

```
SELECT     
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID AS COST_CAT_CODE, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATNME AS COST_CAT_NAME, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COST, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.ITEMDESC AS ITEM, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.CREDITOR, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_NUM AS DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DESCRIPTION, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_DATE AS DATE,  
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PROJECT AS JOB_CODE_STAGE, 
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
FROM         
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID 
INNER JOIN
   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt ON vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID = vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PACOSTCATID

SELECT  
   CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, SUM(COST) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM    
   (SELECT 
        COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, COST 
    FROM   
        vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt 
   ) A
GROUP BY 
    CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
```

This gives me the results I am looking for but the `Total_Cost` produces numbers in a 5 decimal format.

For example:

```
156713.55000
```

What is the best way to get the result to read something along the lines of -

```
156713.55
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the native datatype of the COST field?

Comment: How are you using this query? Usually, you don't format the results in the query. You format the results where you are going to show them. For example, in reporting services you have options to show the fields with a certain format.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629376/microsoft-sql-rounding-off-to-whole-number-need-to-1-decimal-place#comment13777447_10629376).  I believe its the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID AS COST_CAT_CODE, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATNME AS COST_CAT_NAME, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COST, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.ITEMDESC AS ITEM, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.CREDITOR, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_NUM AS DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DESCRIPTION, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.DOC_DATE AS DATE,  
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PROJECT AS JOB_CODE_STAGE, 
           vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION


FROM         vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID INNER JOIN
                      vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt ON vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseCostCatID.PACOSTCATID = vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt.PACOSTCATID



SELECT  CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, CAST(SUM(COST) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS TOTAL_COST

FROM    (  
        SELECT COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, COST 
        FROM   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt 
        ) A
GROUP BY 
        CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only store 2 decimal places, then I wouldn't worry about it.  Almost every language I'm aware of will throw away the extra zeros (except SQL) :)

On the other hand, if you ARE storing more than 2 decimals (i.e. 123.456), then I would use round() instead for accuracy.

```
 ...

SELECT  CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, round(SUM(COST), 2) AS TOTAL_COST  

FROM    (   
        SELECT COMPOUNDNAME AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, COST  
        FROM   vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt  
        ) A 

GROUP BY  
        CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION
```